# Getting android.view.InflateException on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception

I am getting crash reports for some devices caused by an InflateException. The stacktrace doesnt help that much since there is no specific root that causes the exception. Maybe someone faced the same problem? I already found some solutions here using string resources in the styles insteat of hard coded text. But this was always in relation with a button or a textview which was shown in the stacktrace..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2563)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2629)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1485)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5723)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:905)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:766)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at kerasinosapps.apps.diethelper.HomeFragment.onCreateView (HomeFragment.java:92)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2600)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
  at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:434)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:246)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:542)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:210)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1245)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6311)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2526)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:645)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:764)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:835)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Native Method)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:619)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:222)
  at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView (NavigationView.java:385)
  at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init> (NavigationView.java:239)
  at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init> (NavigationView.java:122)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:782)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:835)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:838)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at android.content.res.StringBlock.get (StringBlock.java:65)
  at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString (XmlBlock.java:458)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt (TypedArray.java:1151)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString (TypedArray.java:195)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getString (TintTypedArray.java:150)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle (AppCompatTextHelper.java:397)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes (AppCompatTextHelper.java:209)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init> (AppCompatTextView.java:108)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init> (AppCompatTextView.java:95)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:194)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:115)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:746)
```

Comment: Include your Fragment class to the question. It will be help to detect exact problem whats going wrong with your code.

Comment: I have used Crashlytics and could find the problem. My navigationView could not be inflated properly. It didnt give me a exact line where the problem was but I replaced android:src with app:compatsrc and used Stringresources for font references and then it worked.